# "Being in advantage", as used in the video gaming world of fighting games

Tags: phrases, expressions, nouns, gaming

In fighting games such as Street Fighter, it is common to say that you're "in advantage" to say that you're "in an advantageous state" as opposed to your opponent.

Is it grammatically correct to use "advantage" as a noun and to say that you are in advantage like you would say that you are "in difficulty"?

Comment: 'Advantage' _is_ a noun. Grammar doesn't enter into this. Whether it colligates (the grammatical equivalent of 'collocates') with 'in' is the question you're asking.

Comment: It's probably a bad video game translation. I wouldn't trust Japanese video games to learn English from. (Also, in old video games they probably can't display a long text.)

Comment: "to have the advantage" **in a game**

Comment: This sounds like a game-specific idiom. So grammaticality may not enter into it. Consider how "advantage" is used in tennis, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, as you point out, a modelling after the valid expressions 'in trouble', 'in difficulty', 'in clover' ... but is 'in advantage' acceptable?

There are some reasonable-looking examples of this candidate colligation to be found:

> - Mr. Kerry tried to emphasize the positive aspects of relations with Brazil by focusing on subjects like the government's plans here to
>   send tens of thousands of Brazilian students to American universities
>   and vigorous bilateral trade, tilted in advantage of the United States
>   in the form of an ample surplus. [The New York Times]
> - The simulation results show that the proposed method can handle unpredicted disturbance and data uncertainties very well in advantage
>   of the effectiveness of observation and control. [Applied Mathematical
>   Modelling]
> - The question of building production plants centralized offshore or decentralized onshore is rather in advantage of decentralized
>   production because grid-connected systems are easier to operate,
>   hydrogen transportation will be unnecessary and building on land is
>   less expensive than offshore. [International Journal of Energy and
>   Environmental Engineering]
> - For sex matching, differences between investigated groups were no more than 10%% in advantage of either gender. [Acta Neuropathologica]
> - On the contrary, we detected a non-significant difference in means of 2.3 in SOFA score in advantage of placebo, a trend not explained by
>   the bilirubin changes. [Critical Care]

[All quotes courtesy of [Ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/login/sentences)]

These show that educated writers consider the expression to be acceptable.

But note that all of them include the transitivising preposition/particle 'of': '10% in advantage of women' say. A Google search for << "are in advantage" -"in advantage of" -built >> yields very few relevant and non-substandard results that don't apply to games blogs. One (seeming to mean '[are] advantageous') is

> - That's where particle beams, in our case protons, are in advantage. Due to their finite range and Bragg-peak energy deposition ...

[[S Lautenschlaeger;NIH: National Library of Medicine; 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6721251/)]

Also, the fact that many dictionaries ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/advantage_1), [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advantage), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/advantage), [Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/advantage),   [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advantage), [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=advantage), ) fail to give similar examples (while Cambridge even has a separate entry for say [be in difficulty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-in-difficulty)) points to the fact that it is rather rare. But labelling it as incorrect is overprescriptive. Not that I'd choose 'John is in advantage' over 'John is at an advantage' / 'John has an/the advantage [over Jack]'. Though I'd probably say 'John is winning.'

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! I had the same results when looking around on Google, but it did not sound completely incorrect. This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advantage?q=at%20an%20advantage), the correct expression is ***to be at an advantage***. If we are talking about disadvantages, [according to same source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-a-disadvantage), the correct expresion would be ***to be at a disadvantage***.